How to store Google OAuth access and refresh tokens securely
Context
I'm building an app to manage a Google calendar using React Native and a Node Express server. To log users into Google, I show the consent screen using react-native-google-signin, which provides an authorization code I pass to the server to get the user's Google access token and refresh token (through oAuth2Client.getToken(authorizationCode) as explained in the docs).
Question
After I make the user login to google, I get the authentication token and refresh token on the server. How do I store them so that I can retrieve them securely for later api calls. I am assuming that I cannot simply store it in a database table as any user's data could technically be accessed by any other user.
What recommendations do you have for how to store and retrieve this data securely? And how do I ensure that a user can only retrieve their own information from the database?

do your users have direct access to database?

No, I'm planning on using something like Firebase or Supabase to store data and access it from the backend only

Put the refresh token in the database along side something to help you denote who the user is.
Then make sure you're client id and client secret are stored secure elsewhere.  Without them the refresh token is useless
denote user.
When storing the refresh token you need to be able to be sure that you know one user's refresh token from another's you don't want to mix them.
The easiest way with Google calendar to denote a user is to request the primary calendar.   The most common thing to use would be their email address.
There is a way to figure out who the currently authenticated users email address is via google calendar.
Make a request to the calendars.get method and request primary calendar.
GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary?key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json

Response
The Id of the currently authenticated users primary calendar is ...  their email address.
{
 "kind": "calendar#calendar",
 "etag": "\"j3g2ipQvsbvz0_YlxYi3Mld7A\"",
 "id": "[My email address redacted]",
 "summary": "Linda Lawton ",
 "description": "test",
 "timeZone": "Europe/Copenhagen",
 "conferenceProperties": {
  "allowedConferenceSolutionTypes": [
   "hangoutsMeet"
  ]
 }
}


Thanks, this makes sense! What's the best way to denote who the user is. Since I'd like to authorize the user with Google Calendar and authenticate the user with Google OAuth I'm not quite sure what the best way is to create a user account and add the refresh token to that user

Check edit  little tip from me.
